# Haxe munit with Travis

Tags: travis-ci, haxe, munit

I'm trying to setup Travis to run munit tests for a Haxe library. It installs the dependencies but fails when it tries to run the first test. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Massive Unit - Copyright 2015 Massive Interactive. Version 2.1.0
   haxe -main TestMain -lib munit -lib hamcrest -cp quick-haxe quick-haxe -cp test -swf-version 11 -swf build/as3_test.swf
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:2000/tmp/runner/index.html'
Error: Error running http://localhost:2000/tmp/runner/index.html
```

Repo here: https://github.com/ramchale/quick-haxe

Travis report here: https://travis-ci.org/ramchale/quick-haxe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The munit test runner is trying to run your tests in a browser, which it launches by calling the `open` tool on unix systems. Travis supports headless browsers but munit does not (AFAIK).

You should be able to run the system tests (hxcpp, neko) fine, and for a utility library it will give you some degree of "things are working" confidence.

The Haxe compiler runs JS/Flash tests through SauceLabs, but not using munit.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be some headless or text based browser that would work, but it appears not.